# How do I check for a certain condition and implement it once with reference to pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, pygame

I'm making a pygame game and I want to increase the number of enemies whenever the player reaches 20 kills i.e `kills % 20 == 0`. I have a function `enemy_spawn(number_of_enemies)` and I implemented the following code below. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong because there are infinite enemies once it executes. Please suggest some possible fixes. I have attached only the relevant code. Thank you.

```
number_of_enemies = 5
num_check = False

redrawWindow():
    global num_check
    global number_of_enemies

    if kills%20 == 0 and kills > 1:
        num_check = True
    if num_check:
        number_of_enemies += 1
        num_check = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes sense. After you set num_check to False, the first if condition sets it back to True if the user does not obtain any new kills.

One solution is to also reset the kill count to 0 when num_check is True. For practical use, it may be logical to have a second kill count that keeps track of total kills as well.

Comment: Thank you instead of checking for true false I made it count the kills and set it back to 0 when the enemies increased, its working perfectly now. Do you have any idea why my True False condition didn't work?

Comment: That's great!
I think the True False condition worked, it's just that it since the number of kills did not change "kills%20 == 0 and kills > 1" will return True so num_check would be set to True aswell which means that the number of enemies would be increased again. 
This keeps happening until the player gets another kill as there's no delay, you get a lot of enemies. If the user is able to get a kill somewhere in between, the number of enemies should then be fixed until they reach another multiple of 20.

Answer (score 2):

Change the second `if` to an `elif` so that it does not get executed right after the first `if` sets `num_check = True`. Like this:

```
if kills%20 == 0 and kills > 1:
    num_check = True
elif num_check:
    number_of_enemies += 1
    num_check = False
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense, I'll definitely try it out.